# Responsive navbar with sidebar in vuejs ( bootstrap or bootstrap-vue )

Tags: html, vue.js, navbar, sidebar, bootstrap-vue

I am using Vue.js for my project and I have made a dashboard section but I want something that is responsive and should use bootstrap or bootstrap-vue or plain HTML, CSS.
Attaching the pictures of the dashboard I want to have ->
[image: Main dashboard desktop]
[image: After clicking on hamburger icon]
[image: Mobile view of the same dashboard]
[image: mobile view after pressing hamburger icon]

This is the post I am following
[vuebootstrap b-collapse: when sidebar collapse, change margin-left content div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173948/vuebootstrap-b-collapse-when-sidebar-collapse-change-margin-left-content-div)

My code---

```
  <div>
<b-collapse v-model="visible" id="collapse-4">
  <div class="sidebar scrollable-menu">
    <div style="height: 36%">
      <img
        src="../../../public/images/profile.png"
        style="
          width: 70px;
          height: 70px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          margin-top: 40px;
        "
      />
      <h3
        style="
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 16px;
          margin-top: 15px;
          color: white;
        "
      >
        Hello {{name}}
      </h3>
      <button
        class="mr-2 mt-2 btn"
        style="
          background-color: #595cf5;
          color: white;
          border-radius: 20px;
          font-size: 12px;
          padding: 3px 8px;
        "
      >
        <b-link
          :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/editprofile' }"
          style="background-color: #595cf5; color: white"
          >Edit profile</b-link
        >
      </button>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #3b4664; height: 65%">
      <ul class="ul-dash">
        <li>
          <b-link
            exact-active-class="active"
            :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/' }"
          >
            <b-icon icon="pentagon" class="mr-4"></b-icon>Home</b-link
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <b-link
            exact-active-class="active"
            :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/projects' }"
            ><b-icon icon="files" class="mr-4"></b-icon>Projects</b-link
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <b-link
            exact-active-class="active"
            :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/invitations' }"
          >
            <b-icon icon="person-plus" class="mr-4"></b-icon
            >Invitations</b-link
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <b-link
            exact-active-class="active"
            :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/transactions' }"
            ><b-icon icon="cash" class="mr-4"></b-icon>Transactions</b-link
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <b-link
            exact-active-class="active"
            :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/referrals' }"
            ><b-icon icon="people-fill" class="mr-4"></b-icon>Referrals</b-link
          >
        </li>
        <li>
          <b-link
            exact-active-class="active"
            :to="{ path: '/dashboard/freelancer/resume' }"
          >
            <b-icon icon="file-earmark-text" class="mr-4"></b-icon
            >Resume</b-link
          >
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="contact">
        <span style="color: gray"> Having troubles? </span>
        <p>Contact us</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b-collapse>

<div class="content">
  <b-navbar fixed="top" class="navbar">
  
    <b-navbar-brand href="#"
      ><img
        src="../../../public/images/fevicon.png"
        :class="visible ? null : 'collapsed'"
        :aria-expanded="visible ? 'true' : 'false'"
        aria-controls="collapse-4"
        @click="visible = !visible"
        style="
          width: 30px;
          margin-right: 10px;
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #eaeaea;
          border-radius: 50%;
        "
      />KickStartup
    </b-navbar-brand>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <!-- Right aligned nav items -->

      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
        <!-- <b-nav-item href="#" class="nav-item"
          ><span>Top 1%</span></b-nav-item
        > -->

        <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
          <!-- Using 'button-content' slot -->
          <template #button-content>
            <img
              src="../../../public/images/profile.png"
              style="width: 25px"
            />
          </template>
          <b-dropdown-item to="/dashboard/freelancer/editprofile"
            >Profile</b-dropdown-item
          >
          <b-dropdown-item @click="logout">Sign Out</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
  <div class="maincontent">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
    .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #181e36;
  border-radius: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 270px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.nav-item span {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 2px #efefef, 0px 2px 5px 2px #efefef;
}

.collapse.show ~ .content {
  margin-left: 280px;
}

.collapse.show ~ .content .navbar {
  margin-left: 272px;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.maincontent {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.active {
  color: white !important;
}

.ul-dash li a {
  color: #aeb1ba;
}

.ul-dash {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: -10px;
  color: lightgray;
}
.ul-dash li {
  text-align: start;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ul-dash .active::after {
  content: "• "; /*don't miss the space*/
  color: #595cf5;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  text-align: start;
  background-color: #181e36;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.contact p {
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
}
.contact span {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

js -

```
  props: {},
  created() {
    HTTP.get("/freelancerdash/myprofile", {
      withCredentials: true,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.name = res.data.name;
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        console.log("error hai");
      });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      visible: true,
      name: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["logout"]),
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

/components/Menu/Burger.vue

```
<template>
<div id="burger" :class="{ 'active' : isBurgerActive }" @click.prevent="toggle">
    <slot>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="burger-button" title="Menu">
                    <span class="hidden">Toggle menu</span>
                    <span class="burger-bar burger-bar--1"></span>
                    <span class="burger-bar burger-bar--2"></span>
                    <span class="burger-bar burger-bar--3"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </slot>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import { store, mutations } from '@/store';
export default {
    computed: {
        isBurgerActive() {
            return store.isNavOpen;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle() {
            mutations.toggleNav();
        }
    }
};
</script>
<style>
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* remove blue outline */
button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
.burger-button {
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    border: 2px solid #F56905;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    pointer-events: all;
    transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.burger-bar {
    background-color: #8cae42;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    height: 3px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -1px;
    transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1),
    opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1),
    background-color 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.burger-bar--1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
    transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.burger-bar--2 {
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    /*transform: scaleX(0.8);*/
}
.burger-button:hover .burger-bar--2 {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.no-touchevents .burger-bar--2:hover {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.burger-bar--3 {
    transform: translateY(6px);
}
#burger.active .burger-button {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
#burger.active .burger-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#burger.active .burger-bar--1 {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#burger.active .burger-bar--2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
#burger.active .burger-bar--3 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.menutext{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
</style>
```

/components/Menu/Sidebar.vue

```
<template>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-backdrop" @click="closeSidebarPanel" v-if="isPanelOpen"></div>
    <transition name="slide">
        <div v-if="isPanelOpen"
             class="sidebar-panel">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </transition>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import { store, mutations } from '@/store';

export default {
    methods: {
        closeSidebarPanel: mutations.toggleNav
    },
    computed: {
        isPanelOpen() {
            return store.isNavOpen
        }
    },
    watch: {
        '$route' () {
            if(store.isNavOpen){
                this.closeSidebarPanel();
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.slide-enter-active,
.slide-leave-active
{
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.slide-enter,
.slide-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 150ms ease-in 0s
}

.sidebar-backdrop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.sidebar-panel {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 3rem 20px 2rem 20px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1001;
}
</style>
```

/components/Navigation.vue

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <Burger></Burger>
                <Sidebar>
                    <ul class="sidebar-panel-nav">
                        <li>
                            <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <router-link to="/contact">Contact Us</router-link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </Sidebar>
            </nav>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
              <h1>Hardik Rawat</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Burger from "@/components/Menu/Burger.vue";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Menu/Sidebar.vue";
export default {
    name: "Navigation",
    components: {
        Burger,
        Sidebar
    },
    methods: {
        navHome() {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' });
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.8rem;
}
ul.sidebar-panel-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.sidebar-panel-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```

/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navigation></Navigation>
    <main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Navigation from "@/components/Navigation";
import { store, mutations } from '@/store'
components: {
  Navigation
  },
methods: {
  closeSidebarPanel: mutations.toggleNav,
},
computed: {
  isPanelOpen() {
    return store.isNavOpen
  }
}
</script>
```

/store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const store = Vue.observable({
  isNavOpen: false,
});

export const mutations = {
  setIsNavOpen(yesno) {
    store.isNavOpen = yesno;
  },
toggleNav() {
    store.isNavOpen = !store.isNavOpen;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

bind the `<b-collapse>` with a `v-model` is a misunderstanding of the `v-model` directive.
the `v-model` directive is used to bind form elements, instead to show/hide elements you need to use `v-if` or `v-show`, [here you can learn the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419192/what-is-better-in-vue-js-2-use-v-if-or-v-show) directive. you can see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) the documentation for deep understanding of v-model directive.

for your purpose, allow the bootsrap-vue documentation, instead of using the `<b-collapse>` component you can try with the `<b-sidebar>` component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button v-b-toggle.sidebar-right>Toggle Sidebar</b-button>
    <b-sidebar id="sidebar-right" title="Sidebar" right shadow>
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
        <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
          in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
        </p>
        <b-img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=54" fluid thumbnail></b-img>
      </div>
    </b-sidebar>
  </div>
</template>
```

i think this will work like you want.

Other solution:

there is vuetify, that is a  material Vue UI Library, and precisely [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#bottom-drawer) there is a component that  works like what you asked for.

Comment: I have given the link to the post that I followed and it's working but the navbar and the sidebar are not in sync when clicking on the hamburger  the sidebar should close by sliding effect

Comment: yeah sure wait i am also editing it in the post

Comment: ok, i'm not sure that this solve your problem, but i see that you are using a v-model ti bind the ```<b-collpase>```, and this is an error because the v-model is used to bind input or select. i'm editing my answer to help you

Comment: @Dario What you say about `v-model` is incorrect, it's possible to implement the logic into custom components, which BootstrapVue has done. So using `v-model` on `<b-collapse>` is perfectly fine. There's even a section about it on the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#v-model-support)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you use Vuetify and use the Toolbar component. Then you can make this responsive using display helpers.

Inside the <v-toolbar> tag, we can use the following code:

this will display when screen is medium or greater

```
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                <v-btn outlined @click="$router.push('/login')">
                    <span>
                        Login
                    </span>
                </v-btn>
            </div>
```

this will display when screen is smaller than medium

```
            <div class="d-md-none">
                <v-btn icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">
                    <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </div>
```

This is the code for navigation drawer

```
   <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      absolute
      temporary
      right
    >
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>MENU</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          :href="item.title"
          link
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

where item.title and item.icon is returned by the data() function in your script

Links:

[Vuetify Toolbar Component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#temporary)

[Vuetify Display Helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#visibility)